# Cannot programmatically submit Spark application (with Cassandra connector) to cluster from remote client

Tags: java, linux, amazon-ec2, cassandra, apache-spark

I'm running a standalone Spark cluster on EC2, and I'm writing a application using Spark-Cassandra connector driver and try to submit job to Spark cluster programmatically.
The job itself is simple:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SparkConf conf;
    JavaSparkContext sc;
    conf = new SparkConf()
            .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", host);
    conf.set("spark.driver.host", "[my_public_ip]");
    conf.set("spark.driver.port", "15000");
    sc = new JavaSparkContext("spark://[spark_master_host]","test",conf);
    CassandraJavaRDD<CassandraRow> rdd = javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable(
            "keyspace", "table");
    System.out.println(rdd.first().toString());
    sc.stop();
}
```

Which runs fine when I run that in the Spark Master node of my EC2 cluster.
I'm trying to running this in a remote Windows client.
The problem was from these two lines:

```
    conf.set("spark.driver.host", "[my_public_ip]");
    conf.set("spark.driver.port", "15000");
```

First, if i comment out these 2 lines, application would not throw a exception, but the Executor is not running, with following log:

```
14/12/06 22:40:03 INFO client.AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20141207033931-0021/3 is now LOADING

14/12/06 22:40:03 INFO client.AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20141207033931-0021/0 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)

14/12/06 22:40:03 INFO cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20141207033931-0021/0 removed: Command exited with code 1
```

Which never ends, when I check the worker node log, I found:

```
14/12/06 22:40:21 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:[username] cause:java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [30 seconds]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException: Unknown exception in doAs    
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1134)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:52) 
        at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.run(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:113)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:156)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala)
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [30 seconds]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
... 4 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [30 seconds]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
        at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:107)
        at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
        at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:107)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:52)
        ... 7 more
```

I've no idea what that's about, my guess is that probably worker node could not connect to driver, which probably initially set as:

```
14/12/06 22:39:30 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriver@[some_host_name]:52660]
14/12/06 22:39:30 INFO Remoting: Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@[some_host_name]:52660]
```

Obviously, no DNS is going to resolve my host name...

Since I can't set deploy mode to `"client"` or `"cluster"`, if not via `./spark-submit` script.(Which I think that's absurd...). I try to add a host resolution `"XX.XXX.XXX.XX [host-name]"` in `/etc/hosts` of all Spark Master Worker nodes.

No luck of course...
That leads me to the second, un-comment that two line;

Which gives me:

```
14/12/06 22:59:41 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
14/12/06 22:59:41 ERROR Remoting: Remoting error: [Startup failed] [
akka.remote.RemoteTransportException: Startup failed
        at akka.remote.Remoting.akka$remote$Remoting$$notifyError(Remoting.scala:129)
        at akka.remote.Remoting.start(Remoting.scala:194)
        ...
```

Cause:

```
Caused by: org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /[my_public_ip]:15000
        at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:272)
        at akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$listen$1.apply(NettyTransport.scala:391)
        at akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$listen$1.apply(NettyTransport.scala:388)
```

I double checked my firewall setting and router setting, confirm that my firewall is diabled; and `netstat -an` to confirm port 15000 is not in use (in fact I tried to change to several available port, no luck); and I `ping` my public ip from both other machine and machine from my cluster, no problem.

Now I'm utterly screw up, I just run out of idea try to fix this. Any suggestions? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score -2):

Please check if 15000 is in your security group.